# How to remove the stand connector from the display - Samsung P2770H

Tags: display

I have to return my monitor, Samsung P2770H, for servicing. So, I have to package it in its original packaging. My problem is, I cant remove the stand connector from the display. It is stuck.

Removing the stand from the connector is simple and OK, but I can't pull out the connector from the display. According to the user manual, it should come out fairly easily.

Can anyone suggest a safe way to remove it? The monitor is in warranty, so I do not want under any circumstances to damage it, because it would void my warranty.

Comment: Do you remember plugging it in when you set up the monitor?  Does it definitely look like it is meant to be unplugged?  What kind of connector is it? VGA? DVI? Power?

Comment: It is *not* about the video cable's connector. It's about the the piece of plastic between the (horizontal) stand and the display.

I used the expression "stand connector" because it is how it's called in the user manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, according to the user manual, you just have to push the stand out of the display. Well, both the description and the pictures are misleading in the users manual.

Let's say your monitor is on the table, lying face down. Now, you have to pull the stand out from it, parallel to the monitor (horizontally), but upwards in the same time, so that the end of the connector which is in the display gets pushed a little bit downwards. There is a metallic arch inside the hole which keeps the connector firmly inside and the only way to get it out without braking something is as I described.

Answer (score 4):

I own this monitor (P2770H), and it is relatively easy to remove the stand. Here's how:

Remove all the cables, and leave the circular base attached.  Set the monitor on the floor, tilt the monitor face back as far as it will go.  Stand over the monitor, with your feet on top of either side of the circular base, firmly grasp the bottom edge of the monitor with both hands.  Pull upwards at a slight angle, along the tilt line of monitor.  The monitor should release from the circular base and stem easily.

This stand is designed to be removed in this manner.  You can re-attach the stand and remove it again as you need, without using any tools.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely correct. Pushing it down as the S24B30BL instructions show will not work, and could damage the monitor. I pushed very down very hard as shown, fearing it would break something.

Pulling up on the stand with the monitor screen down on a table and pulling up worked easily. With moderate force, it popped right out. No pixels were harmed in the removal of the stand.

I took a flat-blade screwdriver and put a bevel on the little "catch" molded into the stand connection area. It won't be hard to remove next time.

Answer (score 1):

The base stem is indeed removable but not without some sweat. I pushed the base very firmly to one side which created a small gap on the other side. I forced a piece of thin but rigid plastic into the gap and then applied pressure on the base stem in the other direction. The stem then popped out. I would file the edge from the corner of the tooth that clips into the monitor if I ever assemble something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The following instructions are for Samsung monitors in general and for my Samsung S22C150N monitor, I found the following instructions most helpful:

https://youtu.be/qcA2c7O0E0A

Actually a lifesaver because the textual explanations did not provide enough confidence in using the right kind of force and tilting.

All is well now. Thanks for all who contributed to this thread.